Combining Study Steps with Multiple Geometries in COMSOL
Currently, I am using COMSOL to first solve an eigenmode problem in a simple element and subsequently extracting the displacement from the surface of said element and the results from the eigenmode-study and use those as input for a more complicated geometry.
However, at the moment I have to manually change the geometry, reapply all the necessary (periodic) conditions, and rebuild the mesh each time I want to compute a different eigenmode.
Is there a method in Study-node to specifically compute the values for geometry 1, and subsequently start study 2, which uses the values extracted from study 1, using the withsol operator, and placing those onto the surface of geometry 2?

This is a question you should probably ask on the COMSOL forums.
